# What is the difference between FPN(Feature Pyramid Network), FPNlite and SSDlite?

Tags: references, terminology, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I came across this when I used MobileNet v2 from tensorflow hub. I know that FPN means feature pyramid network and it's better at identifying smaller objects in the frame. However I still don't know why it's called "lite" at some places.

Is it also the same reason as SSDlite? I wasn't able to find a separate paper written for fpnlite and ssdlite architectures although there were new papers like [Nas-fpn](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.07392.pdf) and [mNas-FPN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01106.pdf) which used fpnlite as a baseline.

Can someone please share the original papers or articles written based on fpnlite and ssdlite, so I can find more information? That would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to know what the "lite" stands for in e.g. the model name "SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite" as found in the TensorFlow 2 [Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).
My knowledge is very limited since I just began to get familiar with NNs 2 months ago, but that's what I know for now: ad SSDlite: This framework gets introduced in the [MobileNetV2](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/html/Sandler_MobileNetV2_Inverted_Residuals_CVPR_2018_paper.html) paper as "a mobilefriendly variant of regular SSD". ad